# Remote Access for Printer Connected to USB Port of Modem

Tags: networking, usb, port-forwarding, printer, remote-access

I have connected a Printer directly to the USB Port of my Modem (D-Link 2750U) with the URL http://192.168.1.2:631/printers/M1005

How can I set up port forwarding so that I can access this printer Remotely. I tried forwarding port 9100 to my router IP (192.168.1.1) but it doesnt seem to work.

I guess I need to forward to the IP of the Printer but this is not a network printer and i'm not able to assign a static IP to this printer. All i'm getting is a printer URL while connected to the USB Port. Please help.

Comment: If you're trying to print from the internet, you need to use your public IP (which may not be static). The IP `192.168.1.1` only exists inside your local network. Does it work locally?

Comment: 1. Yes... I understand that I need a public IP and I do have dyndns configured to translate my public IP as well on my router.

2. I am able to print locally but only by using the full URL i.e http://192.168.1.2:631/printers/M1005 - my problem is how do I send the print from an external network to this URL. My router only allows me to forward to an IP address (Ex: 192.168.1.200) but not to a URL

Comment: I have the suspicion that this isn't possible with Windows 10, that Windows Server is required.

Comment: I have windows server 2016. This has nothing do to with the OS. Its a modem + Printer configuration issue. Printer is connected to the modem and port forwarding is being done on the modem